# Can we put custom summary on group summary in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am Populating jqgrid by data from server side from servlet .Now as per my need i have to enable grouping with groupsummary in jqgrid from server side but i am not getting how to achieve this.I am retrieving userdata for groupsummary in the same order in which grouping is displayed in jqgrid..

Here is my Grouping code..

```
grouping: true, 
            groupingView : { groupField : ['extension'],
            groupColumnShow : [true], 
            groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'],
            groupCollapse : false,
            groupOrder: ['asc'], 
            groupSummary : [true], 
            showSummaryOnHide: true, 
            groupDataSorted : true },
```

Currently grouping summary row is empty..

my concern is how to send userdata from server side and populate it in the grouping summary of jqgrid..